# Xcode 5 - How to add Header Search Path and use GDataXMLNode

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, gdataxml

I am trying to use GDataXMLNode to parse an XML file.  I am following the tutorial on this blog:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

My problem is trying to add the GDataXMLNode to my project and getting it to work.  I'm supposed to do something with the configurations, add a Header Search Path, and a few other things, but every single example I've found online is for a previous version of Xcode.  I'm currently using Xcode 5 and I have tried everything (PLEASE prove me wrong), but nothing is working the way it's supposed to in this tutorial.

So, any help as to how I might go about this and get it working together with my iOS project would be much appreciated.  Let me know if I can expound on anything I've said.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should select "All" in Project Settings to show all the parameters, including "Header Search Paths" and "Other Linker Flags".

[image: The image to show "All"]

Comment: Yeah! good call I was wondering about this, too. And thanks for the image despite not being able to post an image right here in-line.

Comment: How is it possible to add search paths to this? Whenever I enter something, it doesn't seem to stick.

Comment: You need to click on + button at the bottom of popup (appears when the input field is highlighted) and enter the path required along with recursive/non-recursive option selected

Comment: for me, adding /usr/local/ssl/include to User Header Search Paths did the trick

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy, follow instruction but remember that GDataXMLNode does not support ARC. You can do the same instruction as Andrey. But I think it should be located in a sub-project, for example: `Library.xcodeproj`. If you want to organize your code formally.

Firstly, create `Library.xcodeproject`, add GDataXMLNode. In `Build Settings`, you also include "Header Search Path" and "Other Linker Flags". But don't forget that GDataXMLNode does not support ARC. Go to `Build Phrases`, under `Compile Sources` menu look for `GDataXMlNode.m` set a Compiler Flag for it with: -fno-objc-arc
[image: Compiler Flag for not approve ARC]
Now, for any sub-project you want to use this library, just go to Build Settings, in User `Header Search Path` properties choose: `../IPLibrary/**` or `../IPLibrary` and choose rescursive option. 
[image: Set header search path to use library]
Now you can include GDataXMLNode. By the way, your project looks more professional, due to lib and source code is split separately. Good luck.

Comment: i tought i added wrongly, then i realize the problem is it not support arc, so check the support one here, life saver -> http://www.michaelbabiy.com/arc-compliant-gdataxml-library/