# How to include OpenSSL on an iOS project in a way that works

Tags: ios, openssl

I have followed all tutorials on the web to do this. Everything works fine, up to the point I add this line on a class:

```
#import <openssl/pkcs7.h>
```

Then I have this error **'openssl/pkcs7.h' file not found**.

How bad can Xcode be? I drag every file to Xcode and the files cannot be found?

This is the structure I have now:

1. the app has 2 targets, openSSL must be installed on the iPad one?
2. I have used [this script](http://www.cvursache.com/2013/08/13/How-To-Build-openssl-For-iOS/)
3. the iPad target is on the following path relative to the base directory path: "Myapp ipad"
4. The script generated two files "libcrypto.a" and "libssl.a". Both files are inside a directory named "lib" inside "Mhapp ipad" (= "Myapp ipad/lib")
5. The script also generated an "include/openssl" directory with a lot of files. I have dragged it to "Myapp ipad". So it is now at "MyApp ipad/include"

How do I fill the search paths, library search paths, whatever to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use CocoaPods - there is an [OpenSSL pod](http://cocoapods.org/?q=openssl)...

Comment: Another alternative is that you need to add a header search path to the include folder that has all the related header files (as opposed to the library search path you already added).  You added the "lib" folder with the two libraries, but you also need to link to the "include" folder that contains a bunch of the headers.    There is an example image of where that is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20567296/173464

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the paths:

[image]

In the `Header Search Path` I use `${SRCROOT}/macOS` and set it to `Recursive`.  Why not specify the directory and `non Recursive`?  I searched for bugs related to `XCode 11` and `Header Search Path`. If I set the full path it did not work.  If I set it to `${SRCROOT}` and recursive it failed.  Odd?

The same `Library Search Path` - the path to the `.a` files - you could just say `${SRCROOT}` but this can get you in trouble if you have multuple `.a` files for different architectures in the same project.  This threw up linking errors for me so I used `${SRCROOT}/macOS`.