# Xcode static link OpenSSL: using wrong headers

Tags: xcode, static, header, openssl

I have compiled OpenSSL and have the two files: libcrypto.a and libssl.a.

In my source file I use:

```
#include <openssl/pkcs7.h>
#include <openssl/objects.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

Then in my project under "Header Search Paths" I add:

```
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Shared/libraries/openssl/include"
```

I add the same thing to "User Header Search Paths"

The two .a library files are linked.

When I compile, Xcode is not using my OpenSSL header files, rather it is pulling them from the standard SDK rather than my custom build:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h
```

How can I force it to use my header files?

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Shared/libraries/openssl/include/openssl/pkcs7.h
```

"Always Search User Paths" is set to "Yes"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set include path in xcode project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project)

Comment: @jww That's not the right duplicate as the accepted answer is to use *Other C Flags*, which cannot be right.

Comment: @trojanfoe - OK, thanks. Perhaps you should add the right answer to the duplicate question. Or provide a better duplicate since this appears to be a frequent question.

Comment: OP: Have you examined the compiler line in the build log to check that the correct include paths are being used?  Setting *Header Search Paths* is the correct thing to do.

Comment: I guess this is no longer a problem?  For people hitting OpenSSL header problems with XCode, I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955003/how-to-include-openssl-on-an-ios-project-in-a-way-that-works/64039858#64039858