# Compiling C++ library in Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode5

I am trying to compile a c++ library in Xcode but I am getting "file not found" errors for the .h files

`#include <Class.h>` does not give any errors

but

`#include <path/to/Class.h>` gives a file not found error.

Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Unless the *parent* folder of `path/to` is in your system header include folder path, `#include <path/to/anything.h>` isn't going to work. Ex: Given the path `/some/path/to`, the folder `/some` should be specified in the system header include path. [**See this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157365/xcode-5-how-to-add-header-search-path-and-use-gdataxmlnode) for an example of adding the path to your project header path list.

Comment: the folder /some is already a part of the project. It is inside a folder named src inside the project's root folder. I added ${SRCROOT}/src/** to header search path. I still get the same error.

Comment: *Which* header search path. I just created a project, and under the source root I created `stuff/more/Header.h`, adding it to the project. I then added `$(SRCROOT)/stuff` to the *target* Header Search Path, and can now `#include <more/Header.h>` without incident. Not sure what your problem with doing the same is.

Comment: are you using the #include in a cpp class or an objective-c class?

Basically, I have just taken the library and added to new Xcode project for testing the library. The library itself is not compiling. The #include statements I am referring to are in cpp classes in the library.

Comment: Straight-up C++ console application for OSX.

Comment: I am trying to run it in an iOS project

Comment: Should work the same in either. Xcode has a Ui path-expander when typing in file names in `#include` braces, once you start one, you can kind of "back out" and see what is available. Someone that has never used Xcode probably thinks I'm speaking a foreign language, but if you've done it, you know what I mean. Its helpful in seeing the paths you think you have available and what is *really* there. It may help you in troubleshooting your path woes.

Comment: I know what you mean. but when I type '#import <Cl', it suggests Class.h but when I start typing the path, it doesn't suggest anything.