# -[UIView setAdUnitID1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, static-libraries, static-linking

I have created a static library of a `UIView` `libLinOneSdk.a`. So i am getting crash when i am using it's property or funcitons. but if i am using `LinDFPBanner.m` Everything is working fine, In Storyboard i have hooked it in nib also. I searched but got no clue why in static libraries this is happening. The problem may be of **Library Search Path**. can anybody help me how can i give library search path.

[image]

```
 self.linBannerView.adUnitID1 = @"XXXX";
    self.linBannerView.rootViewController1 = self;
```

Also app is working fine in ipod touch5 and ipad mini. crashing in simulator and iphone 5s. it can be architech problem.

**Do i need to create a framework rather static library ? because it's not working in iphone 5s**

Comment: Code needed to evaluate add exception break point

Comment: @Spynet- thier is no need for code, because everything is working fine when i am not using static libraies

Comment: Have you set LibrarySearchPath for the libLinOneSdk?

Comment: @confused tap on the black arrow inside the LinDFPBanner class

Comment: @Mrunal- no, i haven't added it. i suppose it should take it automatically. because before it i used libGoogleAdMobAds.a and i never gave it's path.

Comment: @Spynet- i clicked on it and it opens LinDFPBanner.h file

Comment: @Mrunal- Can u help me how to add library search path. because i have never added added search path for library.

Comment: @Confused did u solved ? open project settings and type header search path

Comment: did u got it ? @Confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68212/discussion-between-confused-and-spynet).

Comment: I hope every thing in this stack overflow answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157365/xcode-5-how-to-add-header-search-path-and-use-gdataxmlnode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library libLinOneSdk.a only contains code for the armv7 architecture. iPhone 5s is 64-bit, so you need to include the 64-bit architecture code. You need to [follow instructions for building a fat library first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3647187/211292). After you do that, then you will need to follow the instructions below to get things linked properly.

---

When linked from a static library `LinDFPBanner` is getting dead stripped. To ensure it doesn't get dead stripped you need to add a reference to `LinDFPBanner` in your code. You can do so by adding the following code:

```
- (void)dummyMethod
{
  [LinDFPBanner class];
}
```

This will cause the class to be referenced and it should load properly when needed.

Comment: Thanks, i will work on it and will accept your answer

Comment: @thomasW- thanks for pointing the real problem. i will ask new question how to make in xcode 6. the link you have provided is not working solution

Answer (score 3):

Change the class of your banner view `self.linBannerView` in storyboard to `GADBannerView`.

Double check the same class is there in the `IBOutlet` that you took.

Hope this helps..

Comment: No i am overriding GADBannerView to LinDfpBannerView

Comment: self.linBannerView.adUnitID1 = @"XXXX";

Kindly make sure that **adUnitID1** is not read only & declared globally.

Comment: No this will not work. Do u know something about inheritance...?

Comment: I agree you've inherited the Google's AdMob SDK's classes, but you'll need to add the Google's AdMob SDK .a file and set the library search path accordingly.

Comment: Great!!

It's general good to load your class at the time of app launch.

Comment: no the problem was of iPhone 5s is 64-bit while creating a library